# How to compute the average values corresponding to each row?

Tags: r, plot, raster

I have a raster (matrix) that I would like to compute the average of all values correspond to each latitude

```
library (raster)
r <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10)
r <- setValues(r, 1:ncell(r))
extent(r) = extent(c(xmn=-180,xmx=180,ymn=-90,ymx=90))
plot(r)
```

gives:
[image]

so I want now to do the average and get only one value at each latitude , something like this:

[image]

where `R` is the values presented in the raster (please note that they are different in term of values) here.

Comment: Do you want to plot it on top of the raster or in a new plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct the x and the y values for your line individually. The y-values will just be a sequence from the top to the bottom of the raster:

```
stepsize = (r@extent@ymax - r@extent@ymin) / r@nrows
yvals = seq(r@extent@ymax - stepsize / 2, r@extent@ymin, -stepsize)
```

The x-values will be the mean of each row in your raster:

```
xvals = rowMeans(as.matrix(r))
```

Then you add this to your existing plot:

```
plot(r)
lines(xvals, yvals)
```

or you can plot it on a new graph:

```
plot(xvals, yvals)
```

Comment: one small comment. the line plotted should have the oppsite slop? did you try it?

Comment: @hyat Corrected (apparently I'd originally seen and corrected that in my code but not in my answer)